# exclude from data specific expressions if a group of words occure first

Tags: regex, mariadb, pcre

I am running this in MariaDB 10.0.26 on PCRE 8.39.

Say, i want to exclude Printer,Cartridge,Toner Sets,Kits, or Bundles.

So I wrote this:

```
(?<items>Printer|Cartridge|Toner)(?<sets>Kit|Bundle|Set)(?(?=\g<items>)(?!\g<sets>))
```

The named groups shouldn't much matter, i was just trying everything.

Simply saying, I want this expression:

```
titleField regexp '(?<items>Printer|Cartridge|Toner)(?<sets>Kit|Bundle|Set)(?(?=\g<items>)(?!\g<sets>))' to return 0 and not 1.
```

I am at this point lost what i am doing wrong, even though this must be something FACEPALM(!~~!) worthy.
Please help.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a negative lookbehind, butsince Iit cannot be of unknown width in pcre use a lookahead `^(?!.*(Printer|Cartridge|Toner).*(Kit|Bundle|Set)).*(Kit|Bundle|Set)`

Comment: Wiktor, please post a reply so that i can accept it as correct.

    ^(?!.*(Printer|Cartridge|Toner).*(Kit|Bundle|Set))

You obviously copied in the second part twice.

Thanks for the help, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*(Printer|Cartridge|Toner).*(Kit|Bundle|Set))
```

The lookahead `(?!.*(Printer|Cartridge|Toner).*(Kit|Bundle|Set))` will fail the match if a string contains `Printer`, `Cartridge` or `Toner` (`(Printer|Cartridge|Toner)`) somewhere after 0+ chars other than a newline (`.*`).

You can test [the regex here](https://regex101.com/r/rE0hO9/1).